# MailGetMessageBodyComposite Export RTF Lotus Notes RichText

Tags: c#, richtextbox, lotus-notes

I am trying to export Lotus Notes email Body {Rich Text} to ASP.Net application using c api com components,
I wanted to use below functions... in my c# code.

MailGetMessageBodyComposite (Doc.Handle,.....)

Export RTF

I am not able to find out Handle of the document in C#.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in the C API, but I imagine the rules are similar to COM or LotusScript.  You'll need to get the handle to the note from another object.  Usually you can start from the current session, then get a handle to a particular database, then either do a search within that database or find a note by UNID (or perhaps iterate through a view or folder.)

Here is some documentation on the [NSFNoteOpenByUNID](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/6.0.2/api60ref.nsf/61fd4e9848264ad28525620b006ba8bd/0076007300cf007885255e760066e647?OpenDocument) method that will find a note by UNID if you have a handle to the database.